# Need to confirm how callbacks and errors work in async.each with try-catch blocks

Tags: node.js, async-await, try-catch, async.js

I've been tinkering with this for a few days now and have seen a number of different patterns. In some ways I feel more confused than I did when I began!

`itemsArr` is a list of item objects (`itemObj`) with summary information about each item. Each `itemObj` contains an `itemId` which doubles as the API slug directory. So, I need to iterate through the `itemsArr`, make an API call for each item, and return the updated array with all of the details that were retrieved from each API call. When this is finished, I want to log the enriched array, `enrichedItemsArr` to persistant storage.

It does not matter in what order the API calls return, hence using `async.each`. I also don't want to interrupt the execution if an error occurs. My questions:

1. 'Done enriching array' is printing before execution of `enrichArr()` -> why is `await async.each...` in `enrichArr()` not blocking?
2. I am getting `TypeError: callback is not a function` in the inner try-catch. Not sure why.
3. If I pass `err` to `callback()` in the inner try-catch, will that halt execution?
4. Should I pass `itemsArr` to `processDone` as the 2nd argument? Is there a way to return `itemsArr` to `main()` from the `processDone()` method?
5. Does `err` passed to the final callback contain an array of errors?

```
const main = async () => {
    const itemsArr = items.getArr(); // --> retrieves locally cached itemsArr
    const enrichedItemsArr = await enrichArr(itemsArr); // --> handling the async iterator stuff below
    await logToDB(enrichedItemsArr); // --> helper function to log enriched info to database
    console.log('Done enriching array');

};

const enrichArr = async (itemsArr) => {

    // Outer try-catch
    try {

        const processItem = async (item, callback) => {

            // Inner try-catch
            try {
                const res = await doSomethingAsync(itemID);
                item.res = res;
                callback(); // --> currently getting `TypeError: callback is not a function`
            } catch (err) {
                item.err = err;
                callback(err); // --> not 100% sure what passing err here does...
            }

        };

        const processDone = (err, itemsArr) => {
            if (err) console.error(err); // --> Is err an array of errors or something?
            return itemsArr; // --> how do I return this to main()?
        };

        await async.each(itemsArr, processItem, processDone);

    } catch (err) {
        throw err; // --> if async.each errors, throw
    }

};
```

Comment: What is `async`? Is it some NPM package?

Comment: Started as NPM package yep! https://caolan.github.io/async/v3/

Comment: This looks like a clue: Async accepts async functions wherever we accept a Node-style callback function. However, we do not pass them a callback, and instead use the return value and handle any promise rejections or errors thrown.

Answer (score 0):

Hope this is a good answer for you.

> 1. why is await async.each... in enrichArr() not blocking?

Based on the docs, the async.each will return a promise only if the callback is omitted

[each](https://caolan.github.io/async/v3/docs.html#each)

You're including the callback, the async.each won't return a promise and won't block your code using async/await

> 2. I am getting TypeError: callback is not a function in the inner try-catch. Not sure why.

Your processItem should be a plain function, doing that I was able to use `callback`, seems that the library is not happy when you use async functions

```
const processItem = (item, callback) => {
 const itemId = item;
 // Inner try-catch
 try {
     doSomethingAsync((res) => {
         item.res = res;
         callback()
     });
 } catch (err) {
     item.err = err;
     callback(err); // --> not 100% sure what passing err here does...
 }
```

};

> 3. If I pass err to callback() in the inner try-catch, will that halt execution?

Yes, it will throw an error

> 4. Should I pass itemsArr to processDone as the 2nd argument? Is there a way to return itemsArr to main() from the processDone() method?

If you want to let know the main method that needs to wait, you won't be able to use processDone.

ItemsArr is an object, you can mutate the object and the main method should be able to see those changes, there is no other way if you want to use array.each.

Maybe there is another method in the async library that allows you to return a new array.

Maybe Map is a good option [map](https://caolan.github.io/async/v3/docs.html#map)

> 5. Does err passed to the final callback contain an array of errors?

No, it's a way to let the library know that needs to throw an error.

I created a snippet to allow you to play with the code

```
const async = require('async');

const logToDB = async (items) => {
    items.forEach((item) => console.log(JSON.stringify(item)))
}

const doSomethingAsync = (callback) => {
    setTimeout(() => {
        console.log('processing data')
        callback()
    }, 1000);
}
const main = async () => {
    const itemsArr = [
        {
            itemId: '71b13422-2582-4975-93c9-447b66764daf'
        },
        // {
        //     errorFlag: true
        // },
        {
            itemId: '8ad24197-7d30-4514-bf00-8068e216e90c'
        }
    ]; // --> retrieves locally cached itemsArr
    const enrichedItemsArr =  await enrichArr(itemsArr); // --> handling the async iterator stuff below
    await logToDB(enrichedItemsArr); // --> helper function to log enriched info to database
    console.log('Done enriching array');

};

const enrichArr = async (itemsArr) => {

    // Outer try-catch
    try {

        const processItem =  (item, callback) => {
            console.log('item: ', item);
            const itemId = item;
            // Inner try-catch
            try {
                if (item.errorFlag) {
                    return callback('Test error');
                }
                doSomethingAsync((res) => {
                    item.res = res;
                    callback()
                });
            } catch (err) {
                item.err = err;
                callback(err); // --> not 100% sure what passing err here does...
            }

        };

        await async.each(itemsArr, processItem);
        return itemsArr;
    } catch (err) {
        console.log('Error occurred');
        throw err; // --> if async.each errors, throw
    }
};
main();
```